# How to get values from json array fill a Selection (drop down)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cordova

I am new to jquery and I am currently building an application in phonegap...

I need to get a list of values displayed into the dropdown..

```
 "data": [
    {
      "city_id": "1",
      "city": "test1"
    },
    {
      "city_id": "2",
      "city": "test2"
    },
]
```

I get my data like this... I want to fill these values in the drop down which is found in a form. When the user selects the city in the form I want the form to post city_id when it is posting the form data....

Any kind of help is appreciated....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show your city as text, city_id you can store as attr "city_id" in your tag:

```
<div city_id="(city_id)">(city)</div>
```

and show it on click with jquery.

```
$("div[city_id]").click(function(){
alert($(this).attr("city_id"));
})
```

**Hear some example :**  https://jsfiddle.net/RomanGroovyDev/hh2ydecb/

Answer (score 0):

Its fairly straightforward with jQuery

Html

```
<select></select>
```

JS

```
var d = '"data": [{"city_id": "1","city": "test1"},{"city_id": "2","city": "test2"}]';
var d = JSON.parse('{'+d+'}');

$.each(d.data, function(index, value){
  $('select').append('<option value="'+value.city_id+'">'+value.city+'</option>')
});
```

And there you have it!

Here is a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesharrington/ss94qnbb/1/)

Comment: Will throw a SyntaxError

Comment: I fixed the error. Based on the data you provided you have to put it inside of an object and then parse it.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically load each of these options into a `<select>`html element via jquery.

Each of these options would display the city as text, and city_id as value. JS has a way of parsing JSON into a JS object by the function `JSON.parse()`.

Here's a codeblock you can reference:

```
var data = JSON.parse(*your data above*); // This is now an array
var $menu = $('#menu'); // this is in reference to the <select> menu you have in your HTML that you are appending to
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var city = data[i];
    $menu.append('<option value='+city.city_id+'>'+city.city+'</option>');
}
```

This will populate your menu based on the JSON, and you can wrap the whole thing in a  element so that it will pass the currently selected option on form submit.

Comment: Because the data he posted is in JSON format, not JS object format. Try typing "data" : []; into any piece of JavaScript, and it will return you a syntax error.

Comment: Will throw a SyntaxError

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

**HTML**

```
<select></select>
```

**Data**

```
var dataObj =  {"data": [
    {
      "city_id": "1",
      "city": "test1"
    },
    {
      "city_id": "2",
      "city": "test2"
    },
]}
```

**Script**

Using forEach:

```
dataObj.data.forEach(function (obj) {        
   $("<option />", {value: obj.city_id, text: obj.city}).appendTo($('select'));
})
```

Using for in:

```
for(i in dataObj.data) {
    $("<option />", {value: dataObj.data[i].city_id, text: dataObj.data[i].city}).appendTo($('select'));
}
```

Comment: In general you shouldn't loop over an array with a for loop

Comment: Added forEach as well.